# Написание в соответствии со звучанием или ошибка?

Tags: орфография, устаревшие-слова, старая-орфография

Набрёл в Нацкорпусе на такой пример:

> *Если бы приговор наш был в противную сторону, то он, да и всяк**о**й из нас, и кто бы то ни было, в равном токмо с нами положении, терпеливо бы принял еще десять пощечин, нежели бы захотел при**т**ти в презрение у своих сотоварищей* [А. Н. Радищев. Житие Федора Васильевича Ушакова. 1789].

Хотел спросить о слове *всякой* (всякий). Ведь раньше оно так и произносилось. Ну не О, а шва, если быть точным. Вот, например, писалось же раньше так: Колпа**ш**ный переулок, Све**ш**ная улица, а потом и переулок в Петербурге.

Здесь что: неграмотное написание или допустимое раньше написание в соответствии с произношением?

Потом уже заметил *притти* через "тт". А это — ошибка? Было же написание "при**д**ти" вместо нынешнего "при**й**ти". Не могло оно ещё раньше писаться через "тт"? 1789-й год всё-таки!

Comment: А были ли в 1789 году какие бы то ни было формально утвержденные правила орфографии? (Я не знаю). Если ничего подобного не существовало, то говорить об "ошибке", разумеется, некорректно.

Comment: Наверно. Только не могли в Нацкорпусе править в соответствии с определёнными принципами и старые тексты (не обязательно делая их такими же, как современные)?

Comment: Могли менять старые тексты определённым образом.

Comment: Там вряд ли скан будет, тем более непонятно, как найти нужную его страницу со старым шрифтом.

Comment: Продублирую: *про "всякой" так никто ничего и не сказал.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Кто ищет, тот всегда найдёт (c).*

Вот оригинальное издание 1789 года:

[Источник](https://rusneb.ru/catalog/004735_000094_RuPRLIB12036909/viewer/?page=68)

[image: https://rusneb.ru/catalog/004735_000094_RuPRLIB12036909/viewer/?page=68]

Сюда же добавлю [ссылку](http://xviii.pushkinskijdom.ru/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=r3j278AYpss%3D&tabid=11307) из своего комментария, где рассказывается о том, как обращались с текстами Радищева многочисленные редакторы.

Перенесу сюда весь комментарий, а там удалю.

"В общем, там всё сложно с Радищевым. Его тексты нещадно правили, начиная с самых первых посмертных изданий. Его же сыновья и были первыми редакторами. Вот [здесь](http://xviii.pushkinskijdom.ru/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=r3j278AYpss%3D&tabid=11307) об этом подробно:

> В ряде других случаев можно говорить о явно наблюдаемой тенденции редакторов, впрочем не проявившейся в строгой последовательности: такова замена характерного для Радищева написания глагола «итти» и производных с одной или двумя «т» на «идти».

То есть сам Радищев писал *итти*, *притти*. По-видимому, в Нацкорпус вносили восстановленные тексты".

**Дополнено про "всякой":**

Google Books Ngram Viewer показывает, что с большой вероятностью написание *всякий* есть результат реформы орфографии от 1918 года. В дореформенных текстах пишут *всякой*. Сосуществовали ли оба написания (до революции) - не могу сказать, но логично предположить, что могли сосуществовать. То, что они сосуществовали после реформы, - очевидно, так как не могли все люди сразу переучиться (но старое  написание уже формально считалось ошибкой).

"всякий случай":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"всякой случай":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы молодец, спасибо!

Comment: Про "всякой" так никто ничего и не сказал.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла [такую](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/tesla_non_school/ot-dopustimyh-pritti-ili-pridti-k-priiti-kak-menialos-slovo-poslednie-100-s-nebolshim-let-5cac4b678f2c7600ae261e82) информацию. Там и ссылки на первоисточники есть.

> В 1956 году была проведена реформа, которая касалась в основном изменения орфографии. В соответствии с книжным изданием под названием "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" (утв. АН СССР, Минвузом СССР, Минпросом РСФСР 1956) была сохранена всего лишь одна допустимая форма слова, а именно "приЙти".

Согласно более раннему изданию "Русское правописание" (Я. К. Грот, Санкт-Петербург, 1894) слово "прийти" употреблялось и в виде "притти" в том числе.

Comment: Спасибо, Юлия! Почитаю сейчас.

Comment: Да, неприятно видеть такую пунктуацию: *Русское правописание, подверглось упрощению в 1918 году...* Ладно что-то другое, но как можно ставить запятую между подлежащим и сказуемым, непонятно. Раз уж начал, замечу, что удивляет строгое следование одному заученному правилу, при котором вообще не прислушиваются к интуиции (чуйке, по-вашему ;)), например "Ну, что пойдём?" (перед "что", а не после). Рад, что вы далеки (далеко впереди :)) от таких "грамотеев".

Comment: Думаю, автор что-то меняла в тексте в последнюю минуту, редактировала и сама не заметила, как напортачила. Спасибо, конечно)) Но моя чуйка, как вы видели, часто ошибается)

Comment: Спасибо. Исправила.

Comment: Сделал всё-таки цитату цитатой и поставил упоминание об информации со ссылкой в начало. А то вы сначала цитируете, а потом вдруг находите то, что цитируете. :)) Ещё не совсем понял, что вы называете первоисточником. Там только одна ссылка, в каком смысле она первоисточник?

Comment: Да я просто не знала, как изменить ответ, чтобы его не удаляли. Я на этом сайте недавно и ещё не разобралась со строгими правилами оформления :)) Не хотела вводить в заблуждение (тем что сначала цитирую, а потом вдруг нахожу то, что цитирую), слегка "скопирайтила" источник и всё. :) В качестве источника имела в виду фотографии изданий в статье.

Comment: "Скопирайтила" статью, я имела в виду. Вечером уже совсем голова не работает — тем объяснением, кажется, ещё большую смуту внесла.

Comment: Да не надо было ничего "копирайтить", лучше процитировать, как есть. Так а о каких первоисточниках речь-то?

Answer (score 1):

Оба написания в той или иной мере соответствовали принятым в те времена принципам, все законно. Я, собственно, вижу тут только один пригодный для обсуждения вопрос. Как передавать такие написания в современных изданиях. В остальном тут все понятно.

По поводу ***"всякой"*** - да, это орфографическая норма того времени, тут даже и вопросов нет. Вопросы возникают, надо ли воспроизводить эту норму в современных изданиях. И вот тут-то однозначного понимания нет. Решается конкретно для каждого случая и конкретного издания.

По поводу "притти" интереснее. В принципе-то все сказанное про старую норму и современную в отношении "всякой" справедливо и для этого случая, но тут дело касается не общего правила, а единичного случая, то есть официально зафиксированного колебания в правописании, каковое было устранено только в 1956 г.

Существовали три способа написания одной формы - придти, притти и прийти, исходно имевшие место и для бесприставочного глагола. И по сути никаких указаний на его большую или меньшую нормативность каждой из них не было. В этой ситуации сохранение написания оригинала в современных изданиях выглядит вполне оправданно, своего рода дань уважения автору, выбравшему именно свой, авторский вариант написания.

И в очередной раз процитирую себя. 
*Есть старый корректорский анекдот о том, как надо писать слово "прийти": "Это смотря на каком этаже". В известном москвичам здании "Правды" размещалось несколько редакций (если не путаю, их там давно уже нет). Так вот, на разных этажах предлагалось три варианта. "Придти", "притти" и "прийти". Дело, правда, происходило до 56 г.*

Comment: Спасибо! Я за то, чтобы сохранять "всякой" тоже. Как вы написали, как *дань уважения автору, выбравшему именно свой, авторский вариант написания.* В этом случае отнёсся бы так же. А *приидти, приитти и приийти* специально с двумя И или опечатка? Не сомневался бы, если бы было в одном, а тут во всех.

Comment: @behemothus _...три способа написания одной формы - приидти, приитти и приийти..._ Не смею править, но думаю, что одна "и" везде лишняя.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова да, конечно. Не в форме был. Спасибо.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да не сомневайтесь. Это просто редактура в полусонном состоянии. написал без приставки - а потом механически приставку добавил. )))